# Reusing Layer Selection on Toolbar

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects

I'm working on a custom toolbar for an extension which will have operations that work upon a specific, user-selectable layer.

Is it possible to directly use the layer selector used by ESRI's toolbars in your own toolbar?

For example, the 3D Effects toolbar contains a "Layer:.." combo box for selecting the layer on which to operate.  It includes a full tree of the scene, filtered to certain types of layers.  Is this control a reusable object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since its a toolcontrol its treated like a singleton, in that you can only have one in ArcMap at a time. If it already exists on the 3D toolbar you wont be able to create another instance of it somewhere else. You can see this by trying it manually through the customize dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are refering to the 3DAnalyst_LayerListControl?  This is a ArcMap Command that you can use any command in your own toolbar.

[ArcMap Commands](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET/858a508c-b771-467c-81e6-c6aa72d88f9c.htm)

e.g. using ArcObjects for accessing 3DAnalyst_LayerListControl

```
  Dim pUID As New UID
  Dim pCmdItem As ICommandItem
  ' Use the GUID of the Save command
  pUID.Value = "{2D73B144-8F1C-11D4-A10F-00508BD60CB9}"
  ' or you can use the ProgID
  ' pUID.Value = "esri3DAnalystUI.DDDAnalystLayerListControl"
  pUID.SubType = 3
  Set pCmdItem = Application.Document.CommandBars.Find(pUID)
  pCmdItem.Execute
```

Or reference it directly to your toolbar IToolBarDef class

```
 Public Sub GetItemInfo(ByVal pos As Integer, ByVal itemDef As ESRI.ArcGIS.SystemUI.IItemDef) Implements ESRI.ArcGIS.SystemUI.IToolBarDef.GetItemInfo
        ' Define the commands that will be on the toolbar. The 1st command
        ' ID is the ProgID of the command. Group determines whether the command
        ' begins a new group on the toolbar

        Select Case pos
        Case 0
                itemDef.ID = "esri3DAnalystUI.DDDAnalystLayerListControl"
                itemDef.Group = False

        End Select

    End Sub
```